# Should I edit this question and how?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This question is downvoted, currently -4 ...

- [Is it possible to work long hours in France?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/194748/18412)

... and I don't know why.

SFAIK it was on-topic, and has useful answers.

What's wrong with it -- is it the content/topic, that's either unpopular or deemed "not useful"?

Or are people reacting to the way it's worded?

Should I edit it somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly because you're generalising a whole country into what comes across as a bit ranty with statements that don't really ring true. France is a pretty big place and what works for one person doesn't necessarily work for everyone in terms of productivity.

I have no idea how you could edit it, nor do I really see what the question is. You already seem to have answered yourself.

Comment: The only bit that might be "generalizing a country" is the paragraph which starts, "It France it seems illegal" -- that is a paraphrase of what I've been told, by French people when I try to broach the subject.

Comment: The question is at the end -- "Is it true that nobody works long hours ever? And if they do or can, how?"

Comment: Well, it's obviously untrue that nobody ever works long hours.

Comment: That's what I imagine -- it's contrary to my experience in North America -- yet here I'm told not to. So I don't understand, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

I did not vote, but I'll guess based on the top voted comment. I'll elaborate a bit:

All studies show that working long hours is a net negative. The longer you work in a day, the less effective you get. Whether it's just being slow, or making mistakes or just being exhausted.

In any non-exploitative organisation, working long hours is paid more to compensate the employee for this overtime. So one hour of an 8 hour shift might cost X€, but hours 9, 10 and so on cost (X+)€. This heavily depends on individual contracts and unions though.

So working long hours means the employee is less effective, but costs more, than just leaving it and doing it tomorrow (or hiring a second person if the workload persists).

So the basis of your question is kinda skewed. While you personally might be the one person that goes against the statistics and studies, overall on average, working less hours is more effective, not only for the employee, but also for the employer, if they calculate cost vs result.

Personally, I think this belongs in an answer as a frame challenge (I was just too busy at that time), not a downvote, but I cannot make other people on the internet bend to my will that easily :)

Comment: Which bit of the word "occasionally" in the first sentence was difficult to understand, eh? I've read of productivity studies (for software developers, e.g. [Peopleware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peopleware:_Productive_Projects_and_Teams)) and I like it quite a lof that overwork is not the norm here. I just wondered if there's any flexibility. No-one will tell me that there is but occasionally I hear of someone writing something over a week-end. I don't intend to argue against statistics and it wasn't meant to be a discussion about "on average" nor over any kind of long-term.

Comment: Thank you for answering  this meta-question, anyway.

Comment: Also I didn't get the comment that "it's not just about France" -- there's "France" in the title, in the tags, and twice in the text. Harrumph.

Comment: "All studies show that working long hours is a net negative." - It's not quite that simple. It depends almost entirely on your definition of "long hours".

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Well, there is not a single task I have met in my life, that would not be better done in 2 days of 7 hours each, than one 14-hour marathon session in one day. There might be a lot of external factors that force you into that 14h marathon, or maybe it is a challenge, or "fun", but the OP claimed that doing it once in a while is "better" and I would not agree with that. It is entirely worse, even if "worse" is sometimes a neccessary evil.

Comment: @nvoigt - so "long hours" in this context means "many contiguous/marathon hours"? If so, I agree.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yes, the question referred to 12-14 hours in a single day, that's what I meant with "long hours".